# Combine Rows in Excel Using Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I believe that I can do this in a PivotTable but I am having trouble figuring out exactly how to set it up.  I have data in the following format:

| Initial Condition | Event | Impacted Project | % Over Budget | % Over Schedule |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Condition A | Event 1 | Project 1 | 12 | 30 |
| Condition A | Event 2 | Project 2 | 16 | 41 |
| Condition A | Event 3 | Project 3 | 19 | 23 |
| Condition A | Event 4 | Project 4 | 22 | 43 |
| Condition A | Event 5 | Project 5 | 14 | 17 |
| Condition B | Event 1 | Project 1 | 16 | 32 |
| Condition B | Event 2 | Project 2 | 32 | 46 |
| Condition B | Event 3 | Project 3 | 53 | 24 |
| Condition B | Event 4 | Project 4 | 19 | 16 |
| Condition B | Event 5 | Project 5 | 21 | 25 |

I can't quite write out the table in the format that I need it, but the screenshot below is how I need it to look:

[Final Desired Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQc30.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a relatively straight forward application of pivot tables. Just drag the fields into the columns/rows/values as the screenshot. I have the report layout open to show how you can perform additional fomatting to use tabular format. You can also rightclick on the subtotal rows and remove them (I already have) as well as remove the irrelevant grand totals.You can also double click on the column headers and modify the header to remove the `Sum of` prefix if you want.

The caveat is that for your data you might not want to sum if you have duplicate rows/columns entries. In this case you could use power query with the pivot table option of "do not aggregate"

[image]